# Custom scripts - Combine ng build & firebase deploy?

Tags: angular, firebase, command-line-interface

Every time I want to deploy my Angular project, I have to "ng build" and then "firebase deploy" after it completes.

How do I combine those two actions into one command?

Answer (score 1):

Combine them with `&&` like `npm run ng build && firebase deploy`